# Decreasing OS drive free space on Azure VM running SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, azure, virtual-machines, windows-server-2016, sql

Recently I noticed that drive C: is decreasing in free space on my Azure VM running Windows Sql Server 2016 (doing daily azure VM backups in Recovery Services Vault). Drive C: keeps adding 100-250mb per day and I just cannot trace is what is causing this. Free space is decreasing while total size of all first level folders is not changing. All work and everything related is running on a different drive (I disabled everything possible on drive C).

What I tried so far: checked IIS logs (it's not it), checked treesize app (folder sizes are not changing), Windows Error Reporting disabled

Anyone have any idea what it can be? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Error Reporting does not stop logging, but instead stops error events from being reported to Microsoft.  System and application logs are likely still running and could easily be 100-250mb per day.  Explore overwrite thresholds so that you can maintain event logs (you'll be glad for these logs if you ever have to troubleshoot an issue), while limiting the size of the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking down such a small (but cumulative) free space leak can be tricky. I would use something as [`TreeSize`](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free) to track the space used on a per-directory base.

Moreover, the free version has a 14 day trial for the complete version that supports comparing two VSS snapshots, which can be used to track free space changes more granularly.